# Can a neutrally charged particle disintegrate by EM force?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, standard-model

I have read that it is not possible, but I don't trust my resource a lot. I get that it has no charge when we see it as a particle, but it's made up of quarks, and I don't know if they couldn't interact in some way electromagnetically in order to disintegrate. They certainly interact in order to create magnetic dipole, so... why not disintegration?

(For a bit of knowledge background, I'm studying particle physics in my 5th year bachelor)

Comment: You have to define "particle" . A neutral hydrogen atom can be named a "particle" and an electron scattering off it can send the hydrogen electron over the ionization level , and the the hydrogen has "disintegrated".

Comment: $\pi^0 \to \gamma \gamma$

Comment: Note in the pio example above the pio **is** composed out of quarks and held together by strong interactions, but it is the electromagnetic that decays it.

Comment: Perfeeect, thank you both

Comment: Note there are neutral point particles, the neutrinos, for which this is a true statement. But you should also include the source that you read as it might have context for their statement.

Comment: $J/\psi \to e^+e^-$ is another prominent example.